# Facebook Like button too intruding?

Tags: buttons, layout, facebook

Does anybody feel the Facebook Like button is too intruding in ones UI? Like it doesn't fit in, like it's some cheap plastic thing?

Have anybody ever used JS or something to make any alternatives like a plain text one? If so, has anybody ever done any A/B testing to see if it performs equally well to the original?

http://jsfiddle.net/dwaynie/HqA3H/9/

by Marshall Mathews: http://jsfiddle.net/HqA3H/24/

Thanks!

Comment: Something to possibly consider regarding editing the Like button is that it *could* be against the [TOS from Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) to do so. "IV.4.d. States: You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins, such as the Like button or Like box plugin."

Comment: Is this a user experience design question? Because it feels like you're asking a purely visual aesthetic question. I don't think that's on topic for our site. All of your questions on UX so far have been about visual design or typography. Have you tried [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)? I think it will be more appropriate for your questions.

Comment: UX is the effect of graphic design, so yeah, this is a UX question. Find something better to do than running around closing posts just to improve your reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know that many sites design their own social networking buttons that work into the design of the site.  They often use recognizable aspects of the social logos so that there is good brand recognition but still keep things in the design language of the site.

[Here](http://www.kickstandproductions.net/) is a good example.
[This](http://trenchescomic.com/) is another good one.